# BigQuery - Random numbers repeating when generated inside arrays

Tags: arrays, random, google-bigquery, nested

I made a BigQuery query which involves generating an array of random numbers for each row.  I use the random numbers to decide which elements to include from an array that exists in my source table.

I had a lot of trouble getting the arrays of random numbers to not repeat themselves over every single row.  I found a workaround, but is this expected behavior?  I'll post two "methods" (one with desired results, one with bad results) below.  Note that both methods work fine if you don't use an array, but just generate a single random number.

Method 1 (BAD Results):

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            ARRAY(
                SELECT AS STRUCT
                    RAND() AS random
                FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1)) AS _time
            ) AS random_for_times
    )
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1))
```

Method 2 (GOOD results):

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            ARRAY(
                SELECT AS STRUCT
                    RAND() AS random
                FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1)) AS _time
            ) AS random_for_times
        FROM (SELECT NULL FROM UNNEST([0]))
    )
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1))
```

Example Results - Method 1 (BAD):

```
Row 1
0.5431173080158003
0.5585452983410205
...
Row 2   
0.5431173080158003
0.5585452983410205
...
```

Example Results - Method 2 (GOOD):

```
Row 1
0.49639706531271377
0.1604380522058521
...
Row 2   
0.7971869432989377
0.9815667330115473
...
```

EDIT: See below for some alternative examples that are similar, after Yun Zhang's theory about subqueries.  Your solution was useful for the problem I posted, but note that there are still some cases I am finding baffling.  Also, although I agree that you are probably correct about the subqueries being tied to the problem: shouldn't a subquery (especially one without a FROM clause) be *less* likely to have its results re-used than selecting a "normal" value?  People talk about performance issues with subqueries sometimes, because they are supposedly calculated one time for each row, even if the results may be the same.

Do you agree that this seems like it may be a bug?

The below examples show that it is not necessarily even creating an array of randoms that is the problem -- even performing a sub-select that just happens to have an unrelated array in it can cause problems with RAND().  The problem goes away by eliminating the sub-select, by choosing just the random value from the sub-select, or by including a value inside the array which varies by row. Weird !!!

BAD

```
SELECT
    (SELECT AS STRUCT RAND() AS r, ARRAY(SELECT 1) AS a)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5, 1)) AS u
```

FIX #1 - No subselect

```
SELECT
    STRUCT(RAND() AS r, ARRAY(SELECT 1) AS a)
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5, 1)) AS u
```

FIX #2 - Select only r

```
SELECT
    (SELECT AS STRUCT RAND() AS r, ARRAY(SELECT 1) AS a).r
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5, 1)) AS u
```

Fix #3 - Array contains "u"

```
SELECT
    (SELECT AS STRUCT RAND() AS r, ARRAY(SELECT u) AS a).r
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5, 1)) AS u
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't understood why first query didn't work but I have a simpler version that works for you:

```sql
SELECT (
          SELECT array_agg(RAND()) AS random
          FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1)) AS _time
       ) AS random_for_times
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 10, 1))
```

Update: I later realized that the problem is with `ARRAY(subquery)`, as long as you can avoid using it for your case (like in my query above), you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Yun Zhang.  I posted some additional details as edits above.  I think you may be correct about subqueries, but I found some new interesting cases as noted above.

Comment: I agree with you that the new cases you brought up are weird (or more formally speaking, inconsistent).